# HOW to read pixel data from screen in android using GLES 3

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, glsurfaceview

i am using GLES 3 to create 3D textures and render data in surface view. Is it possible to read this data from the screen/texture some how.

Answer (score 1):

You can read what you've rendered with `glReadPixels()`, but that tends to be slow.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may get better results by rendering to an FBO.

You can find some example code in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika); see for example [EglSurfaceBase#saveFrame()](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/b1df331e89cffeab621f02b102d4c2c25eb6088a/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java#L152).

Comment: But the saveFrame() method calls glReadPixels() ... GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height,
                GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf); ... is that just an empty call ?

Comment: `saveFrame()` is an example of using glReadPixels() to read the pixel data.  If you're asking about FBO rendering, you can find an example of FBO use in the "record GL app" activity (https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java).

Comment: Yes, Im familiar with the activity, and am in the midst of writing a question about implementing it right now - was hoping to tag you so you could weigh in on it if you have a chance...

Comment: tried to tag you in my new question, but was unable to. would love if you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984073/adapting-grafika-recordfboactivity-to-work-with-android-gpuimage